# asp.net core version 5 boilerplate is working on production

Tags: asp.net, aspnetboilerplate

Asp.net core boilerplate version 5 is not working on production. Following error occurred after publishing on server.

1. Spin.js not present
2. moment is not defined
3. Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'unspecifiedClockProvider')
4. $ is not defined

Comment: You can share more details about your problem, add a screenshot, according to what you mention, the bundle may not be published, check this in your layout <script src="~/view-resources/Views/_Bundles/shared-layout.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>